# What can 1 kJ/mol of energy do in reality?

Tags: everyday-life

I am using an approximation of density matrix in a high order series expansion to predict the total internal energy of chemical systems. I realised that the precision of such algorithm is accurate up to 0.00001 Hartree on small chemical systems, which is roughly 0.026kJ/mol's error fluctuation. I wonder in reality, *what can 1 kJ/mol do in our daily life, what physical phenomena can 1 kJ/mol of energy possibly trigger? Or anything that we've been experiencing in our daily life costs roughly 1kJ/mol of energy?* I know *kT* under room temperature is 2.479kJ/mol, but that's still abstract to me. If someone could give me some physical intuitions that would be greatly appreciated!

I mean to leave it as a broad question since we are not picking a specific chemical system to chew on here, any unbiased thoughts are welcome and shall be considered in this post! A collective answer from the various point of view is probably a better way to get one's head around rather than a single aspect answer.

**Please do NOT mark this on hold!** I have discussed with many people and found out that many of which have shown interest to my question, and surely this will benefit many people!

Comment: Perhaps a good starting point is Wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_per_mole ... and then you can come back with precise question that we may answer.